# Dynamically resize div according to dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div called container which contains dynamically created content(paragraphs) through javascript. The problem is that the paragphs aren't shown on the div once they reach beyond the boundaries of the container. To solve this issue, I tried overflow but that just added x,y scrollbars.

What I'm trying to do is increase the height of the container after every parapgraph added i.e. when paragraph is added to container of height 20px, the container increases height to a further 40 px for next paragraph.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>

<a href="#" id="add">Add content</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
width: 120px;
height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/* overflow: auto; */  //As aforementioned, I'm not in favour of scrollbars
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/dfzk0TW.png');
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
  $('#add').on('click', function () {
    $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#container');
  });
});
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I can't see that you're increasing anything.

Comment: try after removing height from css code

Comment: I don't know why question is upvoted? Simply remove `height` from `CSS` code. It solve your problem.

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to get rid of the scrollbar as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v58kue0r/)

remove height from css and use below code

```
$('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('.container');
```

remove # and put dot(.)

Answer (score 0):

this code will get height of container div and than will add 20px in container div.

```
  $(function () {
      $('#add').on('click', function () {
        $('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#container');
        heightWithPx =  $('#container').css('height');
        height = heightWithPx.substr(0,heightWithPx.length-2);
        newHeight = parseFloat(height)+20;
        $('#container').css('height',newHeight+'px');
      });
    });
```